# First qualifier is ignored by a cv-qualification signature

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#1.sentence-4 says:

> The `n`-tuple of cv-qualifiers after the first one in the longest cv-decomposition of `T`, that is, `cv1,cv2,…,cvn`, is called the cv-qualification signature of `T`.

So that means for the type `const int`, the cv-qualification signature is an empty set as the first qualifier is not included; so is the cv-qualification signature for `int`. When following the rules http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#3, this would allow `const int` to be converted to `int` which is definitely not intended. Am I just reading this incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this would allow const int to be converted to `int`

Correct.

> which is definitely not intended.

It is intentional.

> Am I just reading this incorrectly?

Your interpretation seems correct. But the assumption about intentionality is not.

---

An example of such conversion:

```
const T i = 42;
T j = i; // implicit conversion from const to non-const
```